# Fewest steps to show $\sin^2(s) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \cos(2s)$?

Tags: trigonometry

Is there a method for getting from this statement

$
\sin^2(s)
$

to this statement

$
\frac{1}{2}\ -\ \frac{1}{2}\cos(2s)
$

in fewer steps than the following?

$\begin{align}
\cos(2s) &= \cos^2(s) - \sin^2(s) \\
\frac{1}{2} \cos(2s) &= \frac{1}{2} \cos^2(s) - \frac{1}{2} \sin^2(s) \\
-\frac{1}{2} \cos(2s) &= -\frac{1}{2} \cos^2(s) + \frac{1}{2} \sin^2(s) \\
\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \cos(2s) &= \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \cos^2(s) + \frac{1}{2} \sin^2(s) \\
\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \cos(2s) &= \frac{1}{2} ( 1 - \cos^2(s) ) + \frac{1}{2} \sin^2(s) \\
\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \cos(2s) &= \frac{1}{2} ( \sin^2(s) ) + \frac{1}{2} \sin^2(s) \\
\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \cos(2s) &= \sin^2(s) \\
\end{align}$

Comment: @GoodDeeds Good catch, GoodDeeds! Thank you!

Comment: $\cos(2s) = \cos^2s-\sin^2s = 1-2\sin^2s$ and solve for $\sin^2s$...?

Comment: In normal, instantly lead to that statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write $$1=\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)$$
and $$\cos(2x) = \cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x).$$ Subtract these equalities $$1-\cos(2x) = 2\sin^2(x)$$ and divide by two $$\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\cos(2x) = \sin^2(x).$$ Four lines, is it short enough ?

Comment: Holy crap, yes! Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly eliminate several of the steps. I might write it as

$$\cos 2s = \cos^2 s - \sin^2 s\tag{dbl angle formula}$$
$$\cos 2s = 1-2\sin^2 s\tag{$\cos^2$ in terms of $\sin^2$}$$
$$1-\cos 2s = 2 \sin^2 s\tag{subtr both sides from $1$}$$
$$\tfrac12 - \tfrac12\cos 2s = \sin^2 s\tag{halve both sides}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1-\cos(2s)}2=\frac{\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)-\cos^2(s)+\sin^2(x)}2=\sin^2(s).$$

What else ?